# Change the title of references section when using \natbib

Tags: natbib

I have a question regarding `\natbib` package.
Whenever I generate references, package is automatically adding "References" title as in the screenshot below. I'd like to know whether it is possible to create a numbered section with custom title (i.e. force package not to create "References" section automatically)

```
\usepackage{natbib}
.
.
.
\section{Section}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bib}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look to the content of `\thebibliography` with `\meaning\thebibliography`, witch calls `\bibsection`, and (in article class) `\meaning\bibsection` uses `\section *` and `\refname`.

So change `\refname`to 'Whatever you want', and copy paste the content of `\bibsection`, replacing the `\section *` by `\section`:

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{Whatever you want}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{%
   \section{\refname%
            \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}%
   }
}
\makeatother
```

does the job.